# Is there a way to configure popup menu delay for a QToolButton with popupMode == DelayedPopup?

Tags: qt

I'm creating an app with a history like in a web browser: back and forward buttons with a popup menu which is showed on press and hold. The DelayedPopup mode was created exactly for my scenario and it kind of works.

The problem is that the delay used to detect a hold is too short. While I have no trouble with back-forward buttons in, say, Google Chrome, in my app popup menus are popping up regulary when I intend just a simple click.

I suppose setting the delay to a larger value will solve the issue but I can't find a way to do this. The [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtoolbutton.html) says

```
The default delay is 600 ms; you can adjust it with setPopupDelay()
```

but it's clearly wrong or outdated info because there is no setPopupDelay in sight.

Any suggestions?

Upd: Though increased delay considerably helped the popup menu still gets shown from time to time. I think there is a bug in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPopupDelay` was used by Qt 3. Now you have to create your own style by subclassing `QStyle` or one of its subclasses, and re-implementing the [`QStyle::styleHint`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyle.html#styleHint) method.

```
int MyStyle::styleHint(StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const
{
    if (hint == QStyle::SH_ToolButton_PopupDelay)
        return 1200;
    return QStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
}
```

Comment: I think QProxyStyle will be a better alternative to direct subclassing.